# get the OS X username using bash

Tags: macos, bash, username

How can I get the OS X username using bash. The one that is displayed in the Finder UI for example.

[Finder UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKxMJ.png)

For me it's `Clément` but when I run `whoami` or `echo $USER` I got `clement` which is the username that is used in a lower level, by the file system for example (`/Users/clement`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `id -F` which gives the "Full name" of the current user

See the man pages for the command line: `man id` (or take a look at https://ss64.com/osx/id.html)

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer over Gordon Davisson's one because it is the simplest.

Comment: Neat; it looks like this option was added in Yosemite (version 10.10) (after I'd last looked at that man page). I'll leave my answer, since it still works & is needed on older versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your "Real Name" using the `dscl` command:

```
$ dscl /Search -read "/Users/$USER" RealName
RealName:
 Gordon Davisson
```

If you want just the name (e.g. for use in a script), you can clean up the output with `sed`:

```
$ dscl /Search -read "/Users/$USER" RealName | sed '1d; s/^ //'
Gordon Davisson
```

BTW, "username" is generally used to mean the one that `$USER` gets (also called the "short name" or "account name"); the one you want is the "Real Name" or "Full Name" (or sometimes "gecos", for [historical reasons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html)).

Comment: Thank, it works. Thanks also for clarification between username and real name.